# Bootstrap responsive table doesn't scroll horizontally on iOS devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, jasny-bootstrap

I have a table with the following markup:

```
<div class="table-responsive"
    <table class="table table-hover"
        <!-- table data-->
    </table>
</div>
```

As the documentation says, my table should now be able to scroll horizontally. It does work if I use chrome's devices emulator. However, when I try it using a real iPhone (iPhone 5s in this case - tested on iPhone 6 as-well) then I can't scroll the table horizontally at all. I can see the last column displayed in the viewport by default and I just can't scroll it side ways. I tried that in chrome and safari on my iPhone and got the same behavior.

What I tried to do is add the `-webkit-overflow-scroll: touch` but it didn't solve the problem. I've also tried to manually add `overflow-x: scroll` instead of the default `auto` but no avail.

I'm not sure it matters but I also have a bootstrap plugin - offcanvas - by [jasny bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/components/) and I can't scroll that side menu vertically on my iPhone as-well. It all works in the emulators but fails on the real thing.

Maybe those two are connected somehow.

Any help is appreciated.

### Edit:

I have just tested that on an android phone and it seems like I can scroll the table horizontally as expected. However, I still can't scroll the side menu vertically even on android. I guess it means that these problems aren't connected to each other.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found out that by default the `.table` element has `max-width: 100%` and safari "respects" this so it set the width to be 100% which means that the `.table` element isn't overflowing the `.table-responsive` element hence causing it to not be scrollable. This somehow doesn't affect android phones.

The fix was rather easy:

```
.table-responsive .table {
    max-width: none;
}
```

Comment: Bootstrap responsive tables definitely work on iPhone.  I've used them lots of times. There must be some other CSS overriding the bootstrap styles

Comment: @SexyTurnip You might be right. I'm not sure what could've caused it. As it stands setting the max-width to none manually solved the issue on iPhones. I just took a look and `max-width: 100%` is bundled in bootstrap so it must come from the original bootstrap. Maybe there is some bug with iOS 9.1? I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: @Turnip i got the same issue, on my desktop chome everything works, but on iOS chome, it's not working... and due to being placed inside custom elements shadow dom, i'm almost 100% sure it's not overwritten by other styles. for that to happen css would need to leak through dom boundaries, which hopefully can't happen on native web components...

Answer (score 12):

```
.table-responsive .table {
    max-width: none;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch !important;
}
```